# Pyspark conversion from column of vector to doubleType

Tags: python, pyspark

I have column of vector type with one value in each vector. I want to get that value only and keep the column as a doubleType.

example input df:

```
|testcol|
[1.3]|
[1.2]|
[3.4]|
```

desired output df:

```
|testcol|
|1.3|
|1.2|
|3.4|
```

Code I have so far:

```
remove_vector_func = udf(lambda x: list(x)[0], DoubleType())
ex= ex.withColumn("testcol", remove_vector_func("testcol"))
```

This code runs but when I try to show the column, it keeps throwing error:

> expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for
>   numpy.dtype)

I see in printSchema() that the column type is correct:

```
testcol: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Your code works for me, if the name of the column is `testcol` and not `test` because you are giving `testcol` as argument in the `UDF`.

Comment: I meant to put testcol, sorry for the confusion. Are you able to select('test.col').show? Because the error occurs when I do that

Comment: Yes, your code works perfectly. No errors. I copied the code as it is. `ex.show()` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that your lambda function returns an object which matches the return type of your UDF. In this case, you need to convert the object to float type

**Code :**

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

ex = spark.createDataFrame([[1.3],
                            [1.2],
                            [3.4]
                           ], ["test"])

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["test"],outputCol="testcol")
ex = assembler.transform(ex)
ex.show(5)

# UDF for converting column type from vector to double type
unlist = udf(lambda x: float(list(x)[0]), DoubleType())

ex = ex.withColumn("testcol_new", unlist("testcol"))
ex.show(5)
```

**Output :**

[image: output]